# Permission denied Exception when creating new file

Tags: android, createfile

i want to create new file iam using this code

```
try { 
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Contacts.vcf");
            file.createNewFile();

         } catch (IOException ioe) 
          {ioe.printStackTrace();}
```

and using this permission

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" ></permission>
```

but it keeps givinh me exeption that says `Permission denied`

Comment: you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Its a  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use this permission in  manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

when you write any file in `External Storage(SD CARD) or Internal Storage` ,You have to add permission in manifest file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Not only for sdcard, If you want to write on Internal Storage then also this permission needed..

Answer (score 1):

add this permission into your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission to your **AndroidManifest** file as shown below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
.........
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```